# AC Compressor Clutch makes grinding noise

Tags: toyota, ac, 4runner

The AC compressor in my 06 4runner (4wd 4.0L SR5) isn't engaging, and when the clutch coil gets power I hear a grinding sound. I tried replacing the clutch but I still hear a grinding sound and the new clutch looks burnt even though I only had the engine running for a few seconds.

I'm not sure if the compressor is still good. Before I removed the old clutch, the compressor shaft seemed to rotate with only a little resistance (it was easy to turn, but would stop spinning as soon as I stopped pushing it). After putting the new clutch on and testing it, I noticed the compressor shaft will easily turn for a couple rotations and then the resistance increases a lot. Is that normal?

I also tried removing the spacers from the clutch so the compressor is always engaged, and when I turned on the engine (for just a few seconds) the compressor was spinning (this seems like a good sign).

I measured the pressure on the low pressure side and it's reading about 53psi (not sure if that's relevant).

Does it sound like I installed the new clutch wrong and ruined it? Is there a chance the compressor is bad? How do I troubleshoot from here?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!